# How to export Shader from Maya Hypershade using Python

Tags: python, shader, maya

I'm trying to export a vray shading network done in Maya's Hypershade using Maya's Python API cmds (or OpenMaya, or MEL).
I'm aware that I can export shaders from the Hypershade via the Dropdown Menu `File -> Export Selected Network`.
Is there a way to trigger this using Python or does anybody know how to retrieve the actual PySide Widget of the Hypershade so I can try to trigger it that way?

Hope there is someone knowing this out there :)

Answer (score 1):

By enabling 'echo all command', you would see this MEL output :

```
file -op "v=0;" -typ "mayaAscii" -pr -es "/root/mayapath/scene/tmp/test.ma";
```

It means this command is just an export selected from maya.
But if you want to know if this command has more depth, you can find in the MEL output this line :

```
hyperShadePanelMenuCommand("hyperShadePanel1", "exportSelectedNetwork");
```

This the actual proc launched by the button. To see what it does and where it belongs :

```
whatIs hyperShadePanelMenuCommand;
// Result: Mel procedure found in: /root/.../maya2018/scripts/others/hyperShadePanel.mel //
```

whatIs command is really useful and can tell you where belong a command
You can start opening the mel command and find out what is happening in depth

Hope it helps

Comment: Oh sure! Should've thought of enabling "echo all commands" myself. I just don't quite get where you've found the `hyperShadePanelMenuCommand`. When running the `file` command I simply get the path to the exported file. Could you explain this further? Also I couldn't find this in the MEL commands reference.

Comment: This hyperShadePanelCommand is echoed when you do the export button. There is no documentation, it is a special mel proc, you only can open the file that is print with whatIs ! In the other hand, cmds.flle is well documented